# Does a websocket spend outbound data traffic when receiving data?

Tags: python, websocket, protocols, packet

Let's say we have an established websocket connection between our server and a remote server and the remote server from time to time sends some data to us.

So does our websocket connection spend **outbound** data traffic when receiving data?
My guess is **it does not**, because the receiving data gets accumulated in the memory. So when you do a `.recv()`, the websocket just pulls out the data from the memory locally and sends nothing to the other server. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the level of the web socket protocol it is likely that recipient server sends a `ping` message to the originating client every couple of minutes, which responds with a `pong`.

So, the few-tens-of-bytes `pong` message flows back every once in a while.

At the TCP / IP level, the receiver server responds to every second incoming data packet with an ACK packet, comprising 30 bytes.  Incoming data packets can carry up to 1460 bytes of payload data plus the 30 bytes.

So, there's a minimal amount of reverse data transmission, but it's not zero.

If you must have zero reverse transmission you need to use a datagram protocol. But datagram protocols are lossy: there's no way to recover a lost datagram.

Comment: Once the connection is established (which would use outgoing data) there is no more outgoing data required for the listner to be active. So i would say that the answer is actually NO.

Comment: The ping/pong stuff is clear, it does spend data. My question was about merely using a ```.recv()``` in subscriptions such as these: https://docs.deribit.com/#subscriptions

Comment: A websocket is a kind of converted persistent http or https connection. Those sorts of connections all use TCP, which means they all use a small amount of data in the reverse direction, packaged in IP datagrams. Internet routers count traffic datagram by datagram, whereas the programs using the websocket connections only count payload. Maybe i'm but a curmudgeon, but I wish more people learned the basics of the communications layers in school.